# Function to check if dictionary value is occupied

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I'm trying to make a function to check whether a value added to a dictionary already exists.
If a value is already in the dictionary, it should print "Occupied" and not add the value to the existing key.

I have tried to get it to not append when the new input is similar, but it still adds the new input even though it is the same as the previous.

For example, if I add input_v as "Hi" --> XO = {'key': ["Hi"]}

If I were to put in "Hi" again, I then want it to say "Occupied", but as of right now it still adds to the dictionary.

```
XO = {'key': []}
def check_values(input_v):

    value = input_v
    print(XO)
    if value in XO.values():
        print("Occupied")
    else:
        XO['key'].append(value)
```

Comment: `if value in XO['key']`…‽

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the way you referenced the value of the 'key'. Use this:

```
XO = {'key': []}
def check_values(input_v):
    value = input_v
    global XO
    #print(XO)
    if value in XO['key']:
        print("Occupied")
    else:
        XO['key'].append(value)
    #print(XO)
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the answer provided by @deceze too. 
Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: If this helps, you may consider accepting it as the answer

Answer (score -2):

```py
d = dict()
for c in a:
    if c not in d:
        d[c] = 1
    else:
        print("Occupied")
```

Would this work? `a` is a list in this example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).